# How can I move the background image up in CSS, while not moving the text along with it?

Tags: css, header, navigation, background-image

I am having trouble with the active state of the navigation in CSS. I would like to have an arrow aligned with the container, pointed toward the active link, but it won't align unless I move up the text with the background image. The arrow needs to be offset from the text. Any feedback would be appreciated! Thanks!

```
#mainNav ul li.current a,
#mainNav ul li.current-cat a,
#mainNav ul li.current_page_item a,
#mainNav ul li.current-menu-item a,
#mainNav ul li.current-post-ancestor a,
#mainNav ul li.current_page_parent a,
#mainNav ul li.current-category-parent a,
#mainNav ul li.current-category-ancestor a,
#mainNav ul li.current-portfolio-ancestor a,
#mainNav ul li.current-projects-ancestor a
{
  background: url(http://www.jamiestarcevich.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/triangle.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position:center top;
}
```

Comment: Could you please add some HTML code? Otherwise we'll all be guessing what the solution is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pixels or percents, instead of the general `center,top` to position the arrow exactly where you want it

If you need space for the arrow, use `padding-left` (or `padding-right` if RTL)

Side note: looking at your code, you may want to consider using a CSS extension such as [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), which supports nested rules, so you don't have to repeat the element again and again